# c# add-in: Unspecified error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, add-in

I have created an add-in, and every time I try to add it to Tools -> Add-in manager, I get an error.

I have commented all the code from the Connect() method, to be sure that it is not giving me some hidden exceptions.

The  contains the dll name - relative path, because it is easier to just copy it into the Addins folder after each build, rather than having to close Visual Studio to be able to rebuild.

I have tried to give it an absolute path, as well... Either with the absolute path, or with the dll with no extension, I get:

```
Error message: Unspecified error
Error number: 80004005
```

I have also received a "parameter is incorrect" error, as well as "The system cannot find the file specified".

I have gone though the tutorial, more than once. The first time, always, it works, with nothing in the dll - then I close Visual Studio, rebuild, restart, and I am back where I started.

All the issues that have this problem that I could find, suggest using an absolute path (though the documentation says it can be either absolute, relative, or url).

I have tried to set breakpoints in my code but I don't know how to debug this...

Please help !

Comment: What tutorial? That sort of thing does help you know

Comment: how about this one ? http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mgold/AddIns11292005015631AM/AddIns.aspx (I used a microsoft version, but I can't find a detailed one right now)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was caused by the fact that I had both the "**ProjectAddIn - For Testing AddIn**" and the release version "**ProjectAddIn**", with the "**ProjectAddIn.dll**" next to it, in the "**C:\Users\user.name\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Addins**" folder, the way I had seen  it described in the directions...

I did not understand that BOTH xml files represent the same resource, therefore contradicting themselves.

The path in "**ProjectAddIn - For Testing AddIn**" should be pointed at the dll inside the project, and only after I finished with debugging, I can remove this item from the AddIns folder and replace it with the installation items, if so I desire.